# Update column value of another table in After Insert Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I have two different tables: OrderItem and Item. Both tables have a column named "pieces". In the case of table `OrderItem` the pieces are the amount of each item in the OrderItem's list and in the table `Item` the pieces represent the remaining pieces of a product (in a warehouse for example).

So I am building an after insert trigger that will update the pieces in `Items` after an insert is done in `OderItem`

```
delimiter //

create trigger TrgItemPieces
after insert on OrderItem
for each row
begin
 declare PiecesNew int;
  select a.pieces - new.Pieces into PiecesNew from Item a where a.ID = new.ItemId;
  update Item set pieces = PiecesNew where id = new.ItemId;
 end//

delimiter ;
```

But when I do an insert
`INSERT INTO OrderItem VALUES ([OrderID],[ItemID],Pieces);` I get the following error:`Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'Item' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`.
What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

EDIT:
I get the ItemID by doing a select in the insert statement `INSERT INTO ORDERITEM VALUES(1,(select i.ID from Item where i.Name = 'Item1'),5);`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58c0e00f1c84b7717c9b92fee092f9bb - check for triggers on item

Comment: I edited the fiddler https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7acbbd1c0e39476a47228b6554f8ba40

Comment: also, there is something I do differently, I will edit my question. I get the ID of the item for the insert by doing a select on the table Item.

Comment: dbfiddle is case sensitive Item needs to be ITEM

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3e1c0a8b39610b5f6c97ac7250aaa42
I didn't know that

Comment: The select is redundant just

update Item set pieces = pieces - new.pieces where id = new.ItemId;

Comment: I know that. I made that so just to read it a little bit easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a safety measure from MySql to avoid deadlocks.

But you can avoid it by not directly selecting from the table that will be updated via the trigger.

For example by using variables.

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER TrgOrderItemAftIns
> AFTER INSERT ON ORDERITEM
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>   INSERT INTO DEBUG_TABLE (MSG) VALUES (CONCAT('TrgOrderItemAftIns: ', NEW.ITEMID,',',NEW.PIECES));
>   UPDATE ITEM SET PIECES = PIECES - NEW.PIECES WHERE ID = NEW.ITEMID;
> END;
> ```

> ```
> SET @OrderID = (select ID from TabOrder where Name = 'Order 1');
> SET @ItemID  = (select ID from ITEM where Name = 'Item1');
> INSERT INTO ORDERITEM (OrderID, ITEMID, PIECES) VALUES 
> (@OrderID, @ItemID, 5);
>
> SET @OrderID = (select ID from TabOrder where Name = 'Order 1');
> SET @ItemID  = (select ID from ITEM where Name = 'Item2');
> INSERT INTO ORDERITEM (OrderID, ITEMID, PIECES) VALUES 
> (@OrderID, @ItemID, 1);
>
> SET @OrderID = (select ID from TabOrder where Name = 'Order 2');
> SET @ItemID  = (select ID from ITEM where Name = 'Item1');
> INSERT INTO ORDERITEM (OrderID, ITEMID, PIECES) VALUES 
> (@OrderID, @ItemID, 3);
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f3bd73717ef05b982fa1822928c5cc1)*